# Configure aws credentials using go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

I want to create a go function that modify the `.aws/credentials` with values i generate from my code, i checked the aws sdk go v2 documentation and managed to create a code that is working but after the run end and i check the credentials file nothing is changed there, can i use this sdk to achive that?( to also modify the file content)

```
        ctx := context.TODO()
        cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(ctx, config.WithRegion("eu-central-1"),config.WithSharedConfigProfile("default"),
        config.WithCredentialsProvider(credentials.StaticCredentialsProvider{
            Value: aws.Credentials{
                AccessKeyID: "x", SecretAccessKey: "y",
            },
        }))
        if err != nil {
          log.Fatalf("failed to load configuration, %v", err)
        }

        client := sts.NewFromConfig(cfg)
    identity, err := client.GetCallerIdentity(ctx, &sts.GetCallerIdentityInput{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Account: %s, Arn: %s", aws.ToString(identity.Account), aws.ToString(identity.Arn))
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the only thing you can put into the `~/.aws/credentials` file programmatically is `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`.  anything else you add will go into `/.aws/config`

Comment: @KeithRusso thats the way they use it in documentation as well https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config#WithCredentialsProvider